# Populating dropdown based on selection from json to html using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

Hi I want to send data from json file into the dropdowns. There are multiple dropdowns and each dropdown should populate based on selection of other dropdown.
And my json data is large.Data is coming from json to dropdown through ajax call.
What I want is for each selection of dropdown that particular data only should be retrieve and display in dropdown. But when I try I am getting all data in one dropdown only.

When I check my json data in validator it is perfect.

Below is my **HTML code:**

```
<form method="post" action="Upload"  enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <select id="onelevel" name="onelevel"></select>
    <br><br>
    <select id="twolevel" name="twolevel"></select> <br><br>
    <select id="threelevel" name="threelevel"></select> <br><br>
    <select id="fourlevel" name="fourlevel"></select> <br><br>
    <select id="fivelevel" name="fivelevel"></select> <br><br>
    <div class="docu" name="docu">          
        <input type="file" name="data"  accept=".doc,.docx,.xml,application/msword,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document" >
        <button>Upload</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Javascript file data:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'boards.json',
        async:false,

        success: function (data) {                    
            var appenddata;
            var boards=[]
            var board=[]
            var state=[]
            var classes=[]
            var cbse=[]
            var subjects=[]
            var maths=[]
            var chapters=[]

        for(var key in data.boards){
            boards.push(key)
        }

        $.each(boards, function (i,board) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards[board])
            var div_data="<option value ="+val+">"+board+" </option>"
            $(div_data).appendTo('#onelevel');

        });

        for(var key in data.boards.board){
            board.push(key)
        }
        $.each(board, function (i,classes) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board[classes])
            var div_data1="<option value ="+val+">"+classes+" </option>"
            $(div_data1).appendTo('#twolevel');

        });

        for(var key in data.boards.board.cbse.classes){
            classes.push(key)
        }
        $.each(classes, function (i,subjects) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.cbse.classes[subjects])
            var div_data2="<option value ="+val+">"+subjects+" </option>"
            $(div_data2).appendTo('#threelevel');

        });





        for(var key in data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class7.subjects){
            subjects.push(key)
        }
        $.each(subjects, function (i,chapters) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class7.subjects[chapters]['chapters'])
            var div_data3="<option value ="+val+">"+chapters+" </option>"
            $(div_data3).appendTo('#fourlevel');

        });




        for(var value in data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class7.subjects.maths.chapters){
            chapters.push(value)
        }
        $.each(chapters, function (i,terms) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class7.subjects.maths.chapters[terms])
            var div_data4="<option value ="+val+">"+val+" </option>"
            $(div_data4).appendTo('#fivelevel');

        });


        for(var key in data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class8.subjects){
            subjects.push(key)
        }
        $.each(subjects, function (i,chapters) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class8.subjects[chapters]['chapters'])
            var div_data6="<option value ="+val+">"+chapters+" </option>"
            $(div_data6).appendTo('#sevenlevel');

        });



        for(var value in data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class8.subjects.maths.chapters){
            chapters.push(value)
        }
        $.each(chapters, function (i,terms) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.cbse.classes.class8.subjects.maths.chapters[terms])
            var div_data7="<option value ="+val+">"+val+" </option>"
            $(div_data7).appendTo('#eightlevel');

        });







       for(var key in data.boards.board.state){
            state.push(key)
        }
        $.each(state, function (i,classes) {
            var val=JSON.stringify(data.boards.board.state[classes])
            var div_data5="<option value ="+val+">"+classes+" </option>"
            $(div_data5).appendTo('#sixlevel');

        });
```